# Very slow file upload on CF7 Form Submission

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, performance, input

I'm using the [Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) plugin in conjunction with the [Contact form to DB](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/) plugin on my client's site to allow candidates to upload their CVs and my client to access submitted data via wp-admin.

When testing the [Candidate Form](http://www.oresa.co.uk/upload-your-cv/) and submitting a 5kb word document, it takes around 14 seconds for the file to upload and the user response to appear.

I've contacted the hosting company who say there are no issues with the server, so I'm assuming this must be an issue with the back-end code so my questions are:

1. What are the possible reasons for a file upload to take this long
2. What's the best method to troubleshoot such an issue on a live site.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Took me 2.3 sec. And I am in CHINA . Seems reasonable.  BTW and Off the topic - Allowed files only `DOC` and `DOCX` is a bit limited .. at least a PDF should be available as option...

Comment: Pdf option now added - thanks for the tip. It's hosted with HostPapa who I believe are in Canada. The majority of my client's customer base is in UK, and I'm based in Spain. I get a delay of around 15 seconds from submission to response message, which seems unhealthy even given the geographical distance. I'd be very interested to hear more ideas on how to troubleshoot.

Comment: The point is - I do not think there is something terribly wrong . 2.3 ( that´s two point three ) seconds comming from CHINE ( actually , Hong Kong ) is rather normal and not so slow considering the validation / sanitation / DB inject / Upload function and AJAX response ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried form bilbao, Spain and It took 3.45 secs.

I think It could be a routing problem, being the server in Canada it adds load time. Maybe from Hong Kong there are better routing connection to Canada, but Im just speculating.

To trobleshoot this you can use a Firefox´s plugin called [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) "Net" mode, its shows all the calls to the server and the response and time taken to receive it. If it jumps to another page after sending the form press "Persist" to keep data in between page loads.

Im not very familiar to Chrome dev tools, but Im sure it also has a Network tool.

Comment: Thanks Alez - the form submission time seems to vary significantly depending on time of day / geographical location. I use Google developer tools for Chrome and it also has a network tab which is probably the best way to troubleshoot the issue.